# 3D pie graph in matplotlib or other python package

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, pie-chart, pygooglechart

Is there a way to render a 3D pie in matplotlib, or is there a Python package that can generate 3D pies?

**EDIT:** I actually already knew about [`pygooglechart`](http://pygooglechart.slowchop.com/), but I'm looking for something that can be done offline. My apologies for forgetting to include this information. For those who offered `pygooglechart`, thanks for the effort, you have my votes. Question is still open for more ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can use [pygooglecharts](https://web.archive.org/web/20130923225324/http://pygooglechart.slowchop.com/), which is a python wrapper for [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/?csw=1).

[`PyPi: pygooglechat 0.4.0`](https://pypi.org/project/pygooglechart/): Released: Apr 20, 2014

[`GitHub: pygooglechart`](https://github.com/gak/pygooglechart): **Project Abandoned**

For instance:

```
from pygooglechart import PieChart3D

def python_pie3D() :
  # initialize chart object, 250 x 250 pixels
  chart = PieChart3D(250, 250)

  # pass your data to the chart object
  chart.add_data([398, 294, 840, 462])

  # make labels for the slices
  chart.set_pie_labels("Lithuania Bulgaria Ukraine Romania".split())

  # render the image
  chart.download('revenue_east_europe.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
from pychartdir import *

#Data
data = [50, 12, 3,35]

# Labels
labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

# Set pixel
c= PieChart(500, 300)

# set center
c.setPieSize(250, 140, 100)

# Add title
c.addTitle("title")

# Draw
c.set3D()

# Set lebel
c.setData(data, labels)

# Explode all
c.setExplode()

# Output
c.makeChart("threedpie.png")
```